# How to to augment multiple module in single declaration file in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I notice very strange behavior with Module augmentation. I have one `agument.d.ts` file within my `src` folder i.e. `<ROOT>/src/augment.d.ts`. In this file, I am creating one module for Webpack `raw-loader` and also, augmenting existing `hapi` module. The code looks like this:

```
import { Server } from 'hapi';

declare module '*.view.html' {
    const contents: string;
    export default contents;
}

declare module 'hapi' {

    interface Server {
        x: string;
    }
}
```

In my `tsconfig.json` file, I am using the default value for `typeRoots`. And my `include` is set to `["src/**/*.ts"]`,.

**The problem is** - I notice that module augmentation for `hapi` works but not for `*.view.html`; The compiler keeps throwing an error for all the imports associated with `html` files.

However, the strange behavior is when I move definition for `*.view.html` to some other file i.e. - `xyz.html.d.ts`, then it works perfectly.

Is this the intended behavior? Should we have exactly one module augmentation per declaration file? Any rule I am unaware of!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to move the `import` in the module declaration:

```
declare module '*.view.html' {
    const contents: string;
    export default contents;
}

declare module 'hapi' {
    import { Server } from 'hapi';
    interface Server {
        x: string;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't augment `'hapi'` it shadows it. You cannot augment a module and declare an ambient module in a single file. You need two files for this to work.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Please write the correct answer then I'll remove mine.