# Modifying Typescript third party interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to modify thirdparty interface.

I would like to know why does this code work:

```
import { LoadableComponentMethods as OldLoadableComponentMethods } from '@loadable/component';

declare module "loadable__component" {
    
     interface LoadableComponentMethods<Props> extends OldLoadableComponentMethods<Props> {
            requestInitialData(params:string,cookie:string): string;
    }
}
```

And why this does not:

```
declare module "loadable__component" {
    import { LoadableComponentMethods as OldLoadableComponentMethods } from '@loadable/component';  

    interface LoadableComponentMethods<Props> extends OldLoadableComponentMethods<Props> {
        requestInitialData(params:string,cookie:string): string;
    }
}
```

So why the import inside `declare module "loadable__component" {}` not working?

Comment: What error are you getting? But I'd assume that - as always in ES6 - `import` declarations must be top-level.

Comment: I would suggest you use declaration merging over declaring a new interface anyway.

Comment: It is simply not working:


Property 'requestInitialData' does not exist on type 'LoadableComponent<any>'.
  Property 'requestInitialData' does not exist on type 'ComponentClass<any, any> & LoadableComponentMethods<any>'.

Comment: If i try declaration merging and import inside the declare function, i get following error:

Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'LoadableComponentMethods'

Comment: Are you trying to write an augmentation? If so, your `declare module` has the wrong specifier.

Comment: Hi, why would it has the wrong specifier? It is working fine: see first example. I just don't know why can't i import inside the declaration.

Comment: Because you don't import inside an augmentation. If `loadable__component` is the name of a module you are augmenting, rather than defining, then what I said need not apply. If you are augmenting a module, then it must exist elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you, this is clear and i understand it, but i found others saying this is how to augment multiple modules in a single file:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54211733/how-to-to-augment-multiple-module-in-single-declaration-file-in-typescript

Is that answer wrong then?

Comment: @gergokee Those are indeed wrong. They're trying to augment a module and declare an ambient module in a single file which is not possible. When you write `declare module 'specifier' {}` at the top level of a file that is not a module (does _not_ have any top level `import` or `export` statements), you are defining an ambient module. When you write `declare module 'specifier' {}` inside a file that is a module (has one or more top level `import` or `export` statements) you are augmenting a module. I recommend that you begin an augmentation file with `export {}` to prevent refactoring hazards

Comment: @Aluan Haddad
 Thank you very much, do you wish to add your last or the comment before the last as an answer so i can accept it? If not i'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write declare module 'specifier' {} at the top level of a file that is not a module (does not have any top level import or export statements), you are defining an ambient module. When you write declare module 'specifier' {} inside a file that is a module (has one or more top level import or export statements) you are augmenting a module.

The reason the first example works cause that is how you augment a module. The second example is only for occasions when you define an ambient module. In this case i wanted to augment "loadable__component" module so the first works, second does not.